# How to index figures

Tags: captions

I have the figures A and B. I would like them to be indexed as (a) and (b).

```
\begin{figure}[]
\begin{center}
\includegraphics[width=1.0cm]{A}
\includegraphics[width=1.0cm]{B}

\end{center}
\caption{...}  
\label{fig:1}
\end{figure}
```

How can I do that?

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the [`subfig`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/subfig) or [`subcaption`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/subcaption) packages. An example with `subcaption`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}

A cross-reference to subfigures~\ref{sfig:testa} and~\ref{sfig:testb}.
\begin{figure}
\centering
\subcaptionbox{\label{sfig:testa}}{\includegraphics[width=1.0cm]{example-image-a}}
\subcaptionbox{\label{sfig:testb}}{\includegraphics[width=1.0cm]{example-image-b}}
\caption{...}  
\label{fig:1}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

The result:

[image]

I changed from the `center` environment to the `\centering` command to prevent extra additional vertical space from being added.

Comment: And how can I put many indexes in the left side of a figure, at different heights?